# can't add html select option selected into my xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt, if-statement, xslt-1.0

```
I have a select and it works.
<select>
    <xsl:for-each select="//country/state">
        <option value="{id}">
            <xsl:value-of select="city" />
        </option>
    </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```

However, I want to add `selected` attribute for one of the select options.
Unfortunately, I'm unable to insert it. This code doesn't work. I believe there are some problems with `<` and `&lt;`. I've tried both, but didn't find the way to make it work.

```
<select>
    <xsl:for-each select="//country/state">
        <option value="{id}"
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="2 &gt; 1"><!--my true-condition, will be valid for one option only-->
                selected
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        >
        <xsl:value-of select="city" />
        </option>
    </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```

Please **xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"** only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<xsl:attribute>` to achieve the scenario

```
    <select>
        <xsl:for-each select="//country/state">
            <option value="{id}">
                <xsl:if test="2 &gt; 1">
                    <!--my true-condition, will be valid for one option only-->
                    <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
            </option>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </select>
```

Comment: For a fixed string you might as well just do `<xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>` and forget the value-of

Comment: @IanRoberts: Yeah that's true. I will update it. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create attributes in XSLT 1.0 using xsl:attribute.
In HTML you can write `<option selected>` but this is equivalent in XML or XHTML to `<option selected="selected">`. In XSLT you need to generate an attribute with both the name and the value 'selected'.

See change in stylesheet below:

```
<select>
    <xsl:for-each select="//country/state">
        <option value="{id}">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="2 &gt; 1"><!--my true-condition, will be valid for one option only-->
                <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="city" />
        </option>
    </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```